Can homepod mini output to airplay?
I have a whole home audio setup (Airplay via an Airport Express is one of my sources). I want to have music start playing when I come home (via geofencing). I know the Homepod Mini can be a speaker for Airplay, but can it broadcast its music to Airplay?

What does “broadcast its music to Airplay?“ look like. Your automation should be able to play music to multiple rooms. How far have you gotten on the automation side? Perhaps that’s the real problem you face and not asking a mini to stream to presumably another HomePod?

What is your normal source of music to your airplay express?

Here is my setup:

Input sources (Airplay via airport express from iPhone or iPad, roku, etc.) into MC-66 controller: https://www.htd.com/MC-66-Multi-Zone-Controller
Amplifier is https://www.htd.com/DMA-1240
Controller allows for 6 input sources and 6 output zones

Right now I am experimenting with an Alexa Echo since it has a 3.5mm out, so Alexa has a routine that triggers when I get home (via geolocation) that starts Spotify on the Echo; the 3.5mm output is one of the 6 sources on the controller. My desire is to solve this without having to have an Echo.

No model of HomePod sends audio to a remote destination.
They get audio streams and send them to their speaker.
The devices from which you can capture or generate audio to AirPlay receivers is Mac, Apple TV, iOS and iPadOS. Other than a stereo pair of HomePods, they only play to themselves from the network if you don’t use another device to send a stream of audio to the pod speaker.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/105068

